# Bad Request : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to bind request element

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

First Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PIL_P_DOMAINE")
public class PIL_P_DOMAINE {

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "DOMAINE_ID")
    private String DOMAINE_ID;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "DOMAINE_DS")
    private String DOMAINE_DS;

    public PIL_P_DOMAINE() {
    }

}
```

Second Entity:

```
@Entity
        public class PIL_P_DOMAINE_TABLE {

            @NotBlank
            @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "DOMAINE_ID")
            @ManyToOne
            private PIL_P_DOMAINE DOMAINE_ID;

            @NotBlank
            @Column(nullable = false, name = "DATABASE_NM")
            private String DATABASE_NM;

            @NotBlank
            @Column(nullable = false, name = "TABLE_NM")
            private String TABLE_NM;

            @Column(name = "APPLCTN_COLNM_NM")
            private String APPLCTN_COLNM_NM;

            @Column(name = "CRITERE_FILTRE_NM")
            private String CRITERE_FILTRE_NM;

            public PIL_P_DOMAINE_TABLE() {
            }
    }
```

Converter:

```
@Component("domaineToDomTabConverter")
public class DomaineToDomTabConverter implements Converter<Object, PIL_P_DOMAINE> {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DomaineToDomTabConverter.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pIL_P_DOMAINE_SERVICE")
    IService<PIL_P_DOMAINE> domService;

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter#convert(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public PIL_P_DOMAINE convert(Object element) {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String) element);
        PIL_P_DOMAINE dom = domService.findById(id);
        logger.info("Domaine : {}", dom);
        return dom;
    }
}
```

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.fussa.fyby")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    DomaineToDomTabConverter domaineToDomTabConverter;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(domaineToDomTabConverter);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }


    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
        matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

when i try to persist an **PIL_P_DOMAINE** object whitout adding

```
@Override
        public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
            registry.addConverter(domaineToDomTabConverter);
        }
```

to my **AppConfig** class , to object is persisted  (y).
The issue i have is when i want to persist an PIL_P_DOMAINE_TABLE object which contain an object **PIL_P_DOMAINE**, i added **DomaineToDomTabConverter**  to convert to string i will get in form to the object so i added the converter in my **AppCongig** class,with those modifications i cant persist an **PIL_P_DOMAINE** object, i got this error:

> WARN :
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver
>   - Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException:  Failed to convert
>   value of type [com.fussa.fyby.model.PIL_P_DOMAINE] to required type
>   [com.fussa.fyby.model.PIL_P_DOMAINE]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework. core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [com.fussa.fyby.model.PIL_P_DOMAINE] to type
>   [@javax.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bi
>   nd.annotation.ModelAttribute com.fussa.fyby.model.PIL_P_DOMAINE] for
>   value 'com.fussa.fyby.model.PIL_P_DOMAINE@716898c0'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.ClassCastExce ption: com.fussa.fyby.model.PIL_P_DOMAINE
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String

How can i call the converter only if i want to persist my second entity and not the  first ?

Thanks for any advices..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by Parameterizing the type i'm converting from to **String** instead of **Object**

```
@Component("domaineToDomTabConverter")
public class DomaineToDomTabConverter implements Converter<String, PIL_P_DOMAINE> {    

    public PIL_P_DOMAINE convert(Stringelement) {
        //
    }
}
```